# "Could not connect to lockdownd" while attempting to run flutter app

Tags: flutter

I am following the [Get Started](https://flutter.io/getting-started/) tutorial.

I can install everything, `flutter doctor` returns all checkmarks but in the end there is a message:

> idevice_id returned an error:
>   ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -2

Same message appears if I try to run the app using `flutter run` or if I try to list the devices using `flutter devices`.

The tutorial also states that:

> Note: If the Run & Debug buttons are disabled, and no targets are listed, Flutter has not been able to discover any connected iOS or Android devices or simulators. You need to connect a device, or start a simulator, to proceed

I have two devices listed my Android phone and an iPhone simulator. `Run` and `Debug` buttons are ENABLED!

How can I run my app using flutter? It can be either using the command line or IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: I don't know if people are still having this issue. But the way I solved it, it was by reseting my system and running all commands again and everything worked.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/52846630

Answer (score 5):

Disconnect all iOS devices, then:

```
brew uninstall ideviceinstaller
brew uninstall libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew link --overwrite libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD  ideviceinstaller
brew link --overwrite ideviceinstaller
sudo rm -rf /var/db/lockdown/*
```

Connect an iOS device, and choose "Trust" when prompted, after that:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/db/lockdown/
```

Comment: after I ran sudo chmod -R 777 /var/db/lockdown/
it turns from error code -21 to -3
ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -3

Answer (score 2):

This workaround worked for me when loosing the connection:

- close everything (Visual Studio Code, Xcode, Simulator)
- disconnect any physical device
- Start Visual Studio Code
- connect a physical IOS phone
- Start XCode
- build from XCode (it will work)
- Disconnect your physical device
- Start without debug
- You will be prompted to connect to a device

and from there it worked again!

This just to help to debug the loos of connection bug. I have also observed that it begins just after the "stop debugging" command from Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues, and resolved them using the below. Hopefully this will help you.  `flutter doctor` was telling me the answers, but they were a bit buried.  Look for something like this:

```
[-] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 8.3.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 8.3.3, Build version 8E3004b
    ✗ libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller are not installed or require updating. To update, run:
        brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
        brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
        brew install ideviceinstaller
    • ios-deploy 1.9.1
    ✗ ios-deploy out of date (1.9.2 is required). To upgrade:
        brew upgrade ios-deploy
    • CocoaPods version 1.2.0
```

There are four `brew` commands in there to run. When I did them, this problem disappeared for me.  Good luck!

Comment: As I stated in the question, I get all check marks from `flutter doctor`