# How to get flutter run to work reliably on OSX with iPhone?

Tags: ios, flutter

**Environment**

- Laptop: MacOS Mojave 10.14.4
- Flutter: Flutter MacOS v1.2.1 stable
- iPhone: iPhone X running ios 12.2 (16E227)
- Xcode: 10.2 (10E125)

**Problem**

If I try enough times of disconnect, connect, "trust this computer", enter pass code, I will eventually be able to issue

```
$ flutter run
```

and it work.

Nine out of ten times, I get this result:

```
$ flutter run
ideviceinfo returned an error:
ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -19
```

At this point, the iphone will display "Trust this computer?" dialog.  Note, prior to generating this info, I made clean, build, run on this phone using xcode a regular objective c based app and it worked without any issues.

Regarding `$ flutter doctor`results

At one point, it requests I do this `$ brew install --HEAD usbmuxd`.  When I do so, I get this truncated error log:

```
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
./configure: line 16735: syntax error near unexpected token `libplist,'
./configure: line 16735: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libplist, libplist >= $LIBPLIST_VERSION)'

READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting
```

I work around this by doing:

```
$ brew install usbmuxd
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/usbmuxd-1.0.10_1.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded:/Users/davis/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/4c553d1494698a85e85d8dc6de76b96e23ab1ac6450b0f8200050c6cc994e2fe--usbmuxd-1.0.10_1.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring usbmuxd-1.0.10_1.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/usbmuxd/1.0.10_1: 13 files, 120KB
```

Still later in the `$ brew doctor` suggestions I get an error with `$ brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice` but I simply re-issue the command without the `--HEAD` option like above and this step works.

**Other datapoints**

If I open XCode, choose a iphone X simulator (which is my phone model) and run the app, it will open and run the app in the simulator.

If I then choose to deploy to my iPhone, it will run on the iPhone.

After I have run the app on the simulator or iPhone from XCode, I stop the app, close the simulator, close XCode.  Then when I `$ open -a Simulator` it will restart the simulator in iPhone X mode.  I can then `$ flutter run`.  If I then stop the app, close the Simulator, attach the iPhone, `$ flutter run` it prompts to trust this computer and prints the error message shown above.  If rerun `$ flutter run` it does not ask to trust the computer it simply prints the error message.

**Yet another attempt**

This [post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23341) mentions using idevice_id and unpairing the device in xcode.  I attempted this but as soon as I unpair the phone, it will automatically appear in the list as paired.  If I quickly unplug the phone after I unpair, then it will prompt for a trust/dont trust message and say in the dialog the phone is connected but not activated.  If I then use idevice_id and turn off wi-fi, I get similar messages as shown in the post above but it never says "activated".  When I do the -u option, it will print the name of the phone.  Afterwards the error persists.

Comment: Could be to do with you running iOS 12.2. Have you updated to Xcode 10.2?

Comment: Yes. I need to show a line for Xcode.  The 10e125 string is for Xcode and not iOS.  My apologies for transacripton error. iOS is 12.2 and Xcode 10.2 (10E125)

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when device (iPhone) is connected with system, remove device from system and run again.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The fix was found via this [post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24716).  The comment which pointed out to use `$ brew link pkg-config` was the fix for me.  I also attempted to use this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47341623/could-not-connect-to-lockdownd-while-attempting-to-run-flutter-app/48694918) but the failure duing usbmuxd could not be resolved until I did the pkg-config part.